# Mongo query replace with count instead of sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping

I have below aggregate mongo query & want to use mongo count instead of sum to check the performance.

collection sample :

```
[
  {
    "rate": 500,
    "orderDate": 20230101,
    "username": "Brad"
  },
  {
    "rate": 20,
    "orderDate": 20230101,
    "username": "Lewis"
  },
  {
    "rate": 200,
    "orderDate": 20230101,
    "username": "Brad"
  }
]

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      orderDate: 20230101
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      validOrder: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$username",
      approvedOrder: {
        $sum: "$validOrder"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I am getting expected output as :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Lewis",
    "approvedOrder": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "Brad",
    "approvedOrder": 2
  }
]
```

In the above aggregate how cam I replace $sum with mongo count ? Please note my actual condition inside addfields is different, so in above query I only wanted to change the $sum to count.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xe_7veGpEvD

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/#behavior

Comment: [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/#behavior): "_The $count stage is equivalent to the following $group + $project sequence_". And when they say equivalent I'm pretty sure they mean that it's syntactic sugar for the exact same thing. `explain` will show the transformed pipeline that the server executes. Also, I don't think there is any value in having that `$addFields` stage, though it also likely doesn't affect performance much

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$sum: "$validOrder"
```

with

```
$count: {}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sDZkt5Qa9Gj)

Note that `$count` aggregation operator is available from MongoDB version 5.0.

Reference: [`$count` (aggregation operator) Syntax](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count-accumulator/#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from @Yong Shun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76415239/20042973) addresses the actual question that was asked, namely how to use `$count` instead of `$sum` when writing the aggregation. This answer drills down on the "*to check the performance*" component of the question.

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415195/mongo-query-replace-with-count-instead-of-sum#comment134745367_76415195), `$count` effectively provides a more concise syntax for users to express their query. Indeed, check out the `stages` that are reported in the `explain` output from the two commands:

```
> db.collection.explain().aggregate([ { $match: { orderDate: 20230101 } }, {$addFields:{validOrder:1}},{ $group: { _id: "$username", approvedOrder: { $count: {} } } }]).stages
[
  {
    '$cursor': {
      ...
    }
  },
  { '$addFields': { validOrder: { '$const': 1 } } },
  {
    '$group': { _id: '$username', approvedOrder: { '$sum': { '$const': 1 } } }
  }
]
test> db.collection.explain().aggregate([ { $match: { orderDate: 20230101 } }, { $addFields: { validOrder: 1 } }, { $group: { _id: "$username", approvedOrder: { $sum: "$validOrder" } } }]).stages
[
  {
    '$cursor': {
      ...
    }
  },
  { '$addFields': { validOrder: { '$const': 1 } } },
  {
    '$group': { _id: '$username', approvedOrder: { '$sum': '$validOrder' } }
  }
]
```

They are effectively the exact same thing (since `validOrder` has a generated value of `1` in the original pipeline. So there will be no performance difference there.

Without knowing more about the current performance, we can't say anything with certainty about how you might be able to improve it. Broadly I have two general recommendations:

1. Get rid of the `$addFields` stage (either by using `$sum: 1` or using `$count` which generates the same thing). It is not providing any particular value so there's no reason to make the pipeline larger than it has to be.
2. Make sure you have a compound index on `{ orderDate: 1, username: 1 }`.

Taken together, these two things will allow the database to perform this operation as a [covered query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) meaning that it can satisfy it by reading the index alone without fetching documents. This will represent the most efficient way you can perform this operation given the current schema.